# How to use Text.Delimiter in a Text.Combine / concatenate function?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column containing values that I need to split by delimiter and then rearrange + combine.

Instead of doing this in multiple steps by splitting values into multiple columns and then combine them, I'm trying to write my code in a more compact way.

Here's my code, which includes data to create the source table, and my attempt:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKskoSk3Vz89L1S8pz1eKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TextToRearrange = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TextToRearrange", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "rearranged", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([TextToRearrange],"/") & Text.AfterDelimiter([TextToRearrange], "/",1) & Text.BeforeDelimiter([TextToRearrange],"/"))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

My expected result is that the first cell should have a value of one/two/three.

But I can't seem to figure out how to feed the text.delimiter functions into the expression. I've tried using Text.Combine to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to rearrange in powerquery:

```
let  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WKskoSk3Vz89L1S8pz1eKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TextToRearrange = _t]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "rearranged", each let a= Text.Split([TextToRearrange],"/") in Text.Combine({a{1},a{2},a{0}},"/") )
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]